# Setting up go-swagger for first time

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I am new to `go-lang` and so to `go-swagger`. I am following [a blog](https://posener.github.io/go-swagger/) and have installed `go-swagger`  with command :

```
go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger
```

I can see that the `go-swagger` folder is created in

```
C:\Go\bin\src\github.com\go-swagger
```

Now, I added my project path to `$GOPATH` :

```
echo %GOPATH%
C:\Go\bin;D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\Project-2;D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger;
```

When I run

```
D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger>swagger ./swagger.yaml
'swagger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I missing ? Also, I would be grateful if you can suggest me some good material for `go-swagger` as I am finding it very difficult to setup everything. There arent much blogs which can help me do `HELLO WORLD` kinda setup

Thanks

> Update 1:

I tried to set `GOBIN` but no luck with that:

```
D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger>swagger validate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json
'swagger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger>echo %GOBIN%
C:\Go\bin\;
```

> Update 2:

I tried absolute path as suggested as well, but no luck:

```
D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger>C:\Go\bin\swagger validate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json
'C:\Go\bin\swagger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

> Update 3:

Below command worked for me but it doesn't seem to be proper way:

```
go run C:\Go\bin\src\github.com\go-swagger\go-swagger\cmd\swagger\swagger.go  validate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

### Fix for Mac Users

The error should be something like this.

[image]

You should add `%GOBIN%` directory to the path.

**Fix:** Add this line to `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```

Note: My go bin folder is in `$HOME/go/bin` If it is not the case with you use your custom path.

> Restart the terminal once the above changes are made

Answer (score 3):

There are pre-build binary, you just download to any folder, add folder to system PATH to execute from any where.
On windows, you can download https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/releases/download/v0.27.0/swagger_windows_amd64.exe (rename the binary to swagger.exe, and save to C:\Users{your-user}\go\bin)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you install swagger or any other Go binary, the executable is on the `%GOBIN%` directory. To call the `swagger` executable you need to add the `%GOBIN%` directory to the `Windows Path` not the `GOPATH` or call it using the absolute path.

```
D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger> C:\Go\bin\swagger ./swagger.yaml
```

To add the go binaries to the path look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/1199408.

Comment: No luck with absolute path : `D:\Personal\Learning\GoLang\swagger>C:\Go\bin\swagger validate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-expanded.json
'C:\Go\bin\swagger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` .

Answer (score 1):

When you do `go get somepackage/cmd/somecmd` the executable is added, not to `%GOBIN%`, but rather to `%GOPATH%/bin`.

You must therefore add this directory to your path:

```
echo %GOPATH%
// make sure you have a nonempty GOPATH
setx PATH %PATH%;%GOPATH%/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that worked for me on Windows:

`git clone https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger`

`cd go-swagger`

`go install ./cmd/swagger`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have GO installed on your machine. Also a valid swagger.yaml file with end-points details.

First, you need to install go-swagger.
Next Mandatory thing, you would need have is go.mod. Generate one using following command.

```
go mod init ModuleName
```

And then try generating server with the following command :-

```
swagger generate server
```

Boom, this would generate Code with folders for server. Next try generating the client with following command :-

```
swagger generate client
```

That is it. Above steps are bare minimum steps you need to have a Go-rest project. Run docker-less local set up using main.go

Hope this helps!!